# How to use REST in python to delete multiple IDs in interation?

Tags: rest

I am trying to create a script that will do a GET request to retrieve data and then output it so that it can be referenced in the DELETE request URL to run through and delete all the data.

Code:

```py
url = "https://192.168.0.1/api/3/asset_groups/443/assets"

payload = {}
headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Basic',
    "Accept": "application/json"
}

data = requests.get(url, headers=headers, data = payload, verify=False).text

output = json.loads(data)

#Attempting to delete assets by resource field
for resources in output['resources']:
   print(resources)
```

Would I be able to somehow get the resources to be referenced as the id part in the DELETE request

URL:

"https://192.168.0.1/api/3/asset_groups/443/assets/{assetId}"

The resources field just outputs the IDs of the assets I retrieved as such:

```py
102695
105759
105761
```

The list is much longer than just these 3 and is never a set amount. Will always vary hence why I would like it to iterate until all are deleted.

Comment: You would need to tell us what's in the `resources` field. What is the output of the code you've provided to print the resources?

Comment: @WillisBlackburn I have updated the question to include an example of what is in the resources field.